# Trying to loop through list of classes with 'getElementsByClassName'

Tags: javascript, navigation

Im trying to use getElementsByClassName in my Javascript. I know I need to use a loop in order for it to work, but Im not sure how. I only need to use it for the 'showLeft' class. All the others can remain as they are. Here is my JS:

```
var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
        menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),

        showLeft = document.getElementsByClassName( 'showLeft' ),

        showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
        showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
        showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
        showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
        showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
        body = document.body;

showLeft.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
};
showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRight' );
};
showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
};
showBottom.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showBottom' );
};
showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
};
showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
};

function disableOther( button ) {
    if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
        classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showBottom' ) {
        classie.toggle( showBottom, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
}
```

Thanks very much.

Another question:
While i'm here, I thought I might as well ask one other question I have.

This code is for a off-canvas navigation menu which I have set to appear on the right of the screen. I am using the 'menuRight' menu and the 'moveLeft' button. Everything works very well, except I want the navigation menu to disappear when the user clicks on the body of the page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this :

```
var a=document.getElementsByClassName('menuRight');
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  //do stuff. to access the elements use a[i]
}
```

Comment: A little confused.. is this for the first question or the second? If first, do you mean 'showLeft' as opposed to 'menuRight'?

Comment: And for the second question assuming that you want the menuRight to hide when user clicks on element other than the menuRight use Jquery selectors. Here's the link to it : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_not.asp

Comment: Okay, so where do I integrate this code into my code and what do I actually need to put in the //do stuff area?

Answer (score 0):

If all "showLeft" elements are within the same parent element you add the click handler on the parent element and check the currentTarget property.

Otherwise you'll probably need to iterate over each element in the list you get back from getElementsByClassName, however that is kinda inefficent.

You can read more here: http://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

Comment: [*getElementsByClassName*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) returns a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177), not an array.